# 7zip timestamp archive under context menu

Tags: windows-vista, batch-file, 7zip

Does anyone know how I can add a context menu item that would compress a folder and add a timestamp? So that I can right-click a folder and it would give me the option to create something like this: folder_20100528.zip

(I'm posting it here because I figure it's something that's done through a batch file/code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the batch script is what I was trying to figure out ; )

```
SET ZIPPATH="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
SET TIMESTAMP=%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%-%Time:~0,2%%Time:~3,2%
%ZIPPATH% a -tzip "YRH_%TIMESTAMP%" "YRH\*"
```

for now I'm just using a .bat file that I dropped in the directory, I'll try to implement the rest later

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The batch script should be reasonably simple, so create it and throw it in C:\

**On XP:**

- Then open explorer and click the 'Tools' -> 'Folder Options' menu.
- Select the 'File Types' tab.
- Scroll down the extensions list until you find 'File Folder', and highlight it.
- Click the 'Advanced' Button
- This will open a new window, where you can create 'actions' (eg context menu items).
- Simply make a new one, call it what you want, and set up the parameters to send into the batch file.

Comment: Please don't throw arbitrary stuff in the system root. You have no write permission there for a reason, usually.

Comment: On what systems? On linux you don't have write in the root dir. On any version of windows I've ever used with a normal user you have access to write in C:\. What reasons do you have for not wanting people to put files in there?